# jQuery cycle fade effect an mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-cycle

I've just made a slider for a website, with a pager that changes the slide when the mouseover event is triggered. I'm using the jQuery cycle plugin version 2.99

The problem is that the fade effect is gone while using the pagerEvent 'mouseover'.

I don't know what the problem is because when i change the pagerEvent to click the fade effect is working properly.

Can anybody help with this?

Thank you!

The javascript code :

```
function initSlideshow() {
$('#slides')
.before('<div id="nav">')
.cycle({
    timeout: 0,
    speed:   1500,
    pager: '#nav',
    pagerEvent:   'mouseover', // name of event which drives the pager navigation
    pauseOnPagerHover: true
});
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="slider_wrapper">        
    <div id="nav">
        <a id="slide_1" href="#" class="">Dakkapellen</a>
        <a id="slide_2" href="#" class="">Dakkapellen</a>
        <a id="slide_3" href="#" class="">Dakkapellen</a>
        <a id="slide_4" href="#" class="">Dakkapellen</a>
    </div>
    <div id="slides">
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="image"><img src="images/sfeer/sfeer_01.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="title">Dakkapel al vanaf</div>
                <a href="#" title=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="image"><img src="images/sfeer/sfeer_02.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="title">Dakvenster vanaf</div>
                <a href="#" title=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="image"><img src="images/sfeer/sfeer_03.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="title">Nieuwe zolder in &eacute;&eacute;n week</div>
                <a href="#" title=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="image"><img src="images/sfeer/sfeer_04.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="title">Rente fiscaal aftrekbaar!</div>
                <a href="#" title=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: could you give us some code examples or a demo of your page ? jsfiddle maybe ?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the you're using the slideshow itself as the pager. Going to need a "working" example.

Comment: I'd speculate that an animation will change the definition of the object with the mouseover event and as a result would trigger the mouseover again, perpetually restarting the animation. Just a guess without code though.

Comment: Hi,

I posted some of the code. It's impossible to use jsFiddle because there's a lot of js included. Working example is also difficult because it's not allowed to link to our development server.

Thanks again!

Comment: What happens if you change the `pauseOnPagerHover` option to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated a slider using your code [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvhA6/). It works fine with the code you've posted. I'm assuming that you've left out the code for the pagerAnchorBuilder parameter. I think the issue is you may have an event listener that's capturing the mouseover events and possibly stopping propagation by returning false or something else. The problem definitely looks like it's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Ah, I think i have found the problem. The text in the pager is being replaced by Cufon. When I hover the Cufon it doesn't work, when I disable, it does work. Should have checked this before posting, I'm sorry.
Thanks for all the help!